# Program goes into infinite loop when trying to make it guess a random number it selected?

Tags: c++

This is an assignment for class. I am trying to get it to generate a random number and guess what it generated. I am still new in learning c++.I understand that it has to update a variable whenever it iterates but i don't know how to update the variable in the loop. Where am i going wrong?
using namespace std;

```
int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); //seed random number generator

    int actual = rand() % 64 + 1; //random number betweeb 1 and 64
    int tries = 0;
    int searchGridHighNumber = 64;
    int searchGridLowNumber = 1;
    int targetLocationPrediction = ((searchGridHighNumber - searchGridLowNumber) / 2) + searchGridLowNumber;
    cout << "Generate Random enemy location on 8x8 grid....\n";
    cout << "The enemy is located at location #" << actual << " on 8x8 grid 
            with 1
            - 64 sectors.\n ";
              cout
         << "Skynet HK -Aerial Initializing software.....";
    do {
        ++tries;

        if (targetLocationPrediction > actual) {
            cout << "Skynet HK-Aerial rader sending out ping #" << tries
                 << endl;
            cout << "the target location prediction of" << targetLocationPrediction << "was higher than the actual enemy location of"
                 << actual << endl;
            "\n";
            int targetLocationPrediction = searchGridHighNumber;
        }

        else if (targetLocationPrediction < actual) {

            cout << "Skynet HK-Aerial rader sending out ping #" << tries << endl;
            cout << "the target location prediction of" << targetLocationPrediction << "was lower than the actual enemy location of" << actual << endl;
            int targetLocationPrediction = searchGridLowNumber;
        }
        else {

            cout << "enemy was hiding at location #" << actual << endl;
            cout << "Target was found at location #" << targetLocationPrediction << endl;
            cout << "Skynet HK-Aerial Software took" << tries << "predictions to find the enemy location on a grid size of 8x8(64)";
            cout << "Press any key to continue...";
        }
    } while (targetLocationPrediction != actual);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int targetLocationPrediction = searchGridHighNumber;` creates a new `targetLocationPrediction` variable that no longer exists after the {} block that it is in. Your infinite loop is because `targetLocationPrediction` defined in the outer scope is never changed in the loop since instead of just setting values you create new variables. `int targetLocationPrediction = searchGridLowNumber;` is the same bug.

Comment: The solution is to remove the `int` from both of those so you don't declare a new variable.

Comment: @drescherjm i still get a infinite loop when i remove int from both of those. I have tried putting searchGridHighNumber = targetLocationPrediction; after ++tries, and it makes no difference either.

Comment: You need this `targetLocationPrediction = ((searchGridHighNumber - searchGridLowNumber) / 2) + searchGridLowNumber;` in the loop. And you need to change `searchGridLowNumber` and `searchGridHighNumber` in the loop depending on the wrong guess.

Comment: Removing the two uses of `int` is necessary but not sufficient. If the guess is too large the `if` statement makes it larger. If the guess is too small the `else if` makes it smaller. Neither of those changes gets the guess closer to the actual value.

Comment: do  {
      ++tries;
      searchGridHighNumber = targetLocationPrediction;
      searchGridLowNumber = targetLocationPrediction;
      targetLocationPrediction = ((searchGridHighNumber - 
                   searchGridLowNumber) / 2) + searchGridLowNumber;
     if (targetLocationPrediction > actual)

Comment: `searchGridHighNumber = targetLocationPrediction; searchGridLowNumber = targetLocationPrediction; ` you should not set both of these to the same value at the same time.

Comment: so i am putting the formula in the if statement and the else if statement as well as put the searchGridHighNumber = targetLocationPredction in the if statement?

Answer (score 1):

Removing all the unnecessary fiction (it's a good idea to solve the problem before adding fancy output), you have

```
int guess = ((high - low) / 2) + low;
do {
    if (guess > actual) {
        int guess = high;
    }

    else if (guess < actual) {
        int guess = low;
    }
} while (guess != actual);
```

which makes it clearer that you declare new variables when the guess is wrong.
This means that the actual guess is never modified and the loop never terminates, so remove the `int`:

```
int guess = ((high - low) / 2) + low;
do {
    if (guess > actual) {
        guess = high;
    }

    else if (guess < actual) {
        guess = low;
    }
} while (guess != actual);
```

The next problem is that you never shrink the guessing interval – if the guess is too low the next one will be 1; if it's too high the next one will be 64.
Another non-terminating loop, unless the target is 32.

You need to

1. Shrink the interval; the new top is `guess - 1` or the new bottom is `guess + 1`.
2. Make a new guess in the middle of the new interval.

It's easier to compute the guess at the beginning of the loop, as you only need to it in one place:

```
do {
    int guess = ((high - low) / 2) + low;
    if (guess > actual) {
        high = guess - 1;
    }
    else if (guess < actual) {
        low = guess + 1;
    }
} while (guess != actual);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me as if you are reassigning the variable to one of two variables.  The only way the loop would end is if the actual variable was 1 or 64.

What you want to do is create a random number and guess it right?  Well do that then.  In this program, I update the variable only when the user gets the number correct.  I didn't set up any if statements/loops to check for answers over or below the max and minimum values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int actualGuess;
bool tries = false;

     srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); //seed random number generator
     int actual = rand() % 64 + 1;

//Create the random variable value, and create another random value and guess it.
//use the sleep function because if you call rand() during the same second, it will give you the same value.

//Or you can simply use a user entered variable to compare to the 'actual' value

cout << "Skynet HK -Aerial Initializing software....." << endl;
     do{
        cout << "What is the correct number?" << endl;
        cin> actualGuess;

        if(actual == actualGuess){ 
        cout << "Correct!" << endl;
        tries = true;;
        }

        if(actual != actualGuess){
        cout << "Incorrect!" << endl;}
        }while(tries = false);
 return 0;
 }
```

This is some pseudocode for your code. The code below is not compilable, it is designed to understand the flow of your program.

```
 H_Num = 64;
 L_Num = 1;

actual = 23 //say actual rands to 23
TargLoc = ((H_Num - L_Num) / 2 + L_Num)

TargLoc = (64 - 1 )/ 2 + 1)
TargLoc = 63/2 + 1
TargLoc = 32;  //This is what would happen, given the variables you initialized.


tries = 1

if TargLoc > actual
cout - 1
cout - 32
TargLoc = 64

else if
cout 1
cout 32 - 23
TargLoc = 1 

else
cout - 23
cout - 64
cout - 1
cout
```